# I have sent a link to our group to the Teacher. Is it good sentence? Please help me

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, sentence

I have sent a link to our group to the Teacher. Is it good?
**I want to know is there any grammar mistake?**

Comment: It's a little ambiguous.

Comment: Can you please edit it?

Comment: I have sent the teacher a link to our group.

Comment: @KillingTime Alternatively: “I have sent the group a link to our teacher”. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to convey that the teacher is receiving something from your group, you would say "I have sent a link to the teacher from our group."

You can also say "I've sent a link from our group to the teacher." or "I've sent the teacher a link from our group"

It's kind of a weird sentence to say on its own, though.